# In perl, how do i use regexes from one file to match FASTA sequences in another file

Tags: regex, perl, fasta

I have two files, the first (file1) contains several rexeges, while the other(file2) contains FASTA sequences . My intention is to use the regex in file1 to check if they match any Fasta sequences in file2, and print any regexes that match atleast one sequence, with the number of sequences they match. I would have liked to provide my sample code but i couldn't even begin. Please help.

file1 is structured in such a way that each line has an ID, followed by '>>', then the regex;

```
e.g FGER_HWW_PRT >> ..DW[ALK]..[^P]..[VI]{2,4}
    TKAR_GLW_NQW >> [^VKR]{0,2}..FP[D].T.N.Q.

    etc...
```

file2 has an idenfier of a sequence on one line and the sequence on the next line;

```
e.g     >lac9_B: details details
    GFVTSDRWPALKMSRWSLEMVWASRGYPLVNDRMWSWSDDDP
    >serP_A: otherdetails details2
    GFVLSDPPPPALKMSRWSLEMVWASRGYPLVNDPWQRTKRKRKDRTCWASNYIHDRP

          etc...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know where to begin, I would start by removing the need to get the regexes from file1, and just try to write a Perl script which has the one or two of the regexes directly in it and which opens file2 and looks for them. If you get stuck with that, you can post that code here with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started. If you think it might be useful for you, let me know and I can explain what's going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

(Using your .fasta file as input):

```
my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";

my (@head, @seq, %hash);
```

Set a 'match' variable to test your headers for:

```
my $match = "details2";
while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    push @head, $_ if /^>/;
    push @seq, $_ if /^[A-Z]/;
    @hash{@head} = @seq;
}
```

Cycle through the keys (headers) of your hash, and test print the header and sequence if they match your match variable:

```
foreach my $header (keys %hash){
    if ($header =~ /$match/){
    print "Name: $header\tcontains: '$match'\nSequence: $hash{$header}\n" ; 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: >serP_A: otherdetails details2    contains: 'details2'
Sequence: GFVLSDPPPPALKMSRWSLEMVWASRGYPLVNDPWQRTKRKRKDRTCWASNYIHDRP
```